# How to automatic update a rolling months, sums, averages

Tags: microsoft-excel, pivot-table

I have a bit of a problem with a dashboard I am creating. Since this is something that I will be sending out every week, I hope to automate the updating process as much as possible, so I basically only need to update the raw .CSV file and the rest is then changed accordingly.

Since I already have a huge datafile, I would like to do all within pivot tables, if possible:

- First, I want to do a rolling last 13-month view, such that whenever a new month is added, the pivot automatically changes the months in the pivot. In Excel terms I need latest month, latest month-1, latest month-2, ..., latest month-12.
- Second, I am doing various sums of last 3- and 6-month sales.
- Third, I am looking to do dynamic weeks of inventory. This will be something like current stock divided by average last 12 weeks of sales.

Comment: I'm assuming then that your raw CSV file will contain data from more than 13 months? How is the CSV data being linked to your spreadsheet?

Comment: Yes, data from 13 months. Just a simple pivot based on the data.